# redux saga yield call throw error TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of null

Tags: redux, redux-saga, localforage

I have app which loads 'favorites' each time user logs in. Data are loaded from IndexedDB using localforage. It works perfectly when app is starting fresh (after window refresh). When I logout and login (root saga task running) call that loads 'favorites' data throws error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of null

at step:

```
export function* handleRecoverFavorites() {
  try {
    const resp = yield call(localforage.getItem, 'favorites')
```

saga code extract:

```
export function* handleRecoverFavorites() {
  try {
    const resp = yield call(localforage.getItem, 'favorites')
    if(resp) {
      yield put(recoverFavorites(resp))
      yield all(resp.map(symbol => put(getTickPricesSubscribe(symbol))));
          }
  } catch(err) {
    let response={"errorDescr":"Error whilst recovering favorites: "+err}
    yield put({ type: types.RESPONSE_ERR, response })
    console.log(response.errorDescr)
  }  
}


function* runAtStartupSubscirptions(socket, streamSessionId) {
  yield fork(send, {"command": "getBalance", "streamSessionId": streamSessionId }, socket );
  yield fork(handleRecoverFavorites)
  yield fork(handleRecoverCharts)
  while(true) {
    yield call(delay, STREAMING_PING_TIME)
    yield call(send, {"command": "ping", "streamSessionId": streamSessionId }, socket );
  } 
}

function* handleRequests(socket) {
  let streamSessionId = yield select(state => state.get("auth").get("streamSessionId"))

  while(true) {
    yield take(types.STREAMING_SOCKET_STATUS)
    if(socket.readyState === 1)
      yield fork(runAtStartupSubscirptions, socket, streamSessionId)
  }
}

export function* handleStreamingConnection() {
  let server = yield select(state => state.get("auth").get("server"))
  const socket = yield call(createWebSocketConnection, server+"Stream" )
  const socketChannel = yield call(createSocketChannel, socket, null)
  const task = yield fork(handleRequests, socket)

  let channelMsg;
  do {
    channelMsg = yield take(socketChannel)
    if(channelMsg.socketResponse) {
      const response = channelMsg.socketResponse;
      switch (response.command) {
        case "candle":
          yield put({ type: types.GET_CANDLES_STREAMING, response })
          break;

(...)

        default:
          console.log("unrequested data: "+response)
      }
    }
    if(channelMsg.socketStatus) {
      console.log(channelMsg)
      yield put({ type: types.STREAMING_SOCKET_STATUS, channelMsg })
    }  
  } while (channelMsg.socketStatus!=="Disconnected")
  yield cancel(task)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  while(true) {
    // Wait for log-in
    yield take(types.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
    const handleStreamingtask = yield fork(handleStreamingConnection)
    yield take([types.LOGOUT_REQUEST, types.RECONNECTING ])
    yield cancel(handleStreamingtask)
    const channelMsg={"socketStatus" : "Disconnected"}
    yield put({ type: types.STREAMING_SOCKET_STATUS, channelMsg })
  }
}
```

I will be appreciated for any suggestions.

I have added console.log line to see result without saga call:

```
export function* handleRecoverFavorites() {
  try {
    console.log(localforage.getItem('favorites'))
    const resp = yield call(localforage.getItem, 'favorites')
```

it returns every time Promise with correct value:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__:Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:Array(1)
0:"CHFPLN"
length:1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it, instead of direct call of localforage method inside "yield call", I have wraped it into separate class:

```
export class LocalDataService {  
  getData = ( param ) => {
    return localforage.getItem(param)
      .then( result => result)
      .catch( reason => reason)
  }
}

export function* handleRecoverFavorites() {
  try {
    const api = new LocalDataService()
    const resp = yield call( api.getData, 'favorites')
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Sylwek reply, and investigating a bit further, the issue relies on the internal setItem context not binding as we expected.
By calling localforage with the following form, we can avoid creating a class:

```
yield call([localforage, localforage.getItem], 'favorites')
```

This fixed it for me :)
Check the *this context* section in saga docs: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects/

Comment: Thank you for the great response and the article!